# gevent clean Greenlet exit

Tags: python, gevent

I'd like to hear other people's solution to a problem I'm seeing in the default way which gevent uses to signal an exit state to greenlets.

I like the ability of doing a group.kill( timeout = 3 ), but the way it's translated in the greenlet is the generation of a GreenletExit. This is fine for very simple local computation code, but I find it very limiting for anything more complex. Here is an example (using ZMQ):

```
def myGreenlet( zFrom, zTo ):
    msg = zFrom.recv_multipart()
    zTo.send_multipart( msg )
```

I would like to be able to tell my greenlet to exit, but to ignore GreenletExit if it's in the middle of receiving/transmitting anything. If that's the case, send whatever message you have received, and only then exit cleanly.

GreenletExit is just a bull in a china shop. So the solution I've come up with is to not use that mechanism at all other than as a last recourse, instead I manually handle signaling to the greenlet to exit via an event like this:

```
def myGreenlet( stopEvent, zFrom, zTo ):
    while not stopEvent.wait( 0 ):
        msg = zFrom.recv_multipart()
        zTo.send_multipart( msg )
```

As you'll note, this is not very good either unless I start adding timeouts in all my IO calls (like the recv) and add a timeout in the .wait() to slow it down, which is against the philosophy of gevent.

I've looked for better solutions documented anywhere but have had no luck. What's the general consensus, any well supported methods for this kind of problem?

Comment: Obviously for the second example I could also do a select between the zFrom and stopEvent, but it still seems like a lot of extra code for a problem that must be fairly common.

Comment: Does my answer give you any inspiration to you? If so, please accept my answer, it's important to me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The more wisely way to solve this may let each greenlet handle its own timeout exception. The greenlet coordinator shouldn't perform too much intervention on the greenlets. What the coordinator should do is `joinall` of them and then ask the greenlets for the result or exception, on which it depends to do some follow-up actions.

To explain in detail:

```
def my_greenlet():
    try:
       # do something here...
    except KindOfTimeOutException, e:
       raise e
```

The greenlets coordinator:

```
greenlets = [gevent.spawn(my_greenlet) for i range(10)]
gevent.joinall(greenlets)

# NOTE: On this time, the greenlets all have quit by themselves
for greenlet in greenlets:
    e = greenlet.exception
    if e:
        # handle exception...
    else:
        result = greenlet.value
        # do something...
```

Comment: @user3395838 "this introduces too much coupling between the coordinator and the greenlet", it's what i want to say to you about your question. In my answer, I let the greenlets handle the exception themselves, and the coordinator only check the result.

Comment: @user3395838 There's no contradiction between my solution and your case. The Actor could joinall of the greenlets and check the results, then decide whether to spawn_later some new greenlets.